# C programming-3 testing condition in if statements

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   float marks;
   char sports;
   char dance[10];

   printf("Enter your marks:\n");
   scanf(" %f",&marks);

   printf("Do you play sports?? <y/n>\n");
   scanf(" %c",&sports);

   printf("Do you dance?? <yes/no>\n");
   scanf(" %s",dance);

   if((marks >=70) && (sports == 'y') &&(dance == "yes"))
  {
    printf("You are a Good Student\n");
} else{
    printf("You are a Average student\n");
}

return 0;




}
```

In any scenario am not getting output as -you are a good student
am getting output if i make dance as char but i want it to solve using string.
can anyone tell me whats wrong in this code.

Comment: don't compare char* with `==`. Use strcmp.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. I've rewritten your question. I am not getting the expected output 'you are a good student'. I am getting the expected output if i make dance of char type, but i want it to work when dance is of string type. Can anyone tell me what's  wrong in this code?

Answer (score 3):

When you do `dance == "yes"` you are comparing two pointers (the pointer to the first element in the array `dance`, and the pointer to the first letter in `"yes"`). And those two pointers will never be the same.

To compare string you need to use the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function:

```
strcmp(dance, "yes") == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcmp()` in your code instead of `dance == "yes"` because dance read the three characters, plus the implicit `\0` terminator and  your condition becomes false.

Comment: 'So, your condition every become false.' Where is the So? Imho your explanation doesn't make sense although the solution is correct. I think Joachim has an better explanation.